# Save the results of combn() into a dataframe

Tags: r

Using the combn() in console we can see a list of results.

```
> combn(3, 2, simplify = FALSE)
    [[1]]
    [1] 1 2

    [[2]]
    [1] 1 3

    [[3]]
    [1] 2 3
```

How is it possible to save the result to a dataframe with one column which will have the results?

Example of the new dataframe:

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

Comment: Do you want to save the results in one column itself or do you want to separate it into multiple columns?

Comment: @RonakShah thank you for your comment. I want ony the results. That's why I mention one column. I edit the answer with the example of expected output

Comment: `do.call("rbind", combn(3, 2, simplify = FALSE))` ?

Comment: Or `as.data.frame(t(combn(3, 2)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant, but this should work :

```
data.frame(t(data.frame(combn(3, 2, simplify = FALSE))),row.names = NULL)
```